# What can cause git rebase to see conflicts while there are none?

Tags: git

My feature branch "feature/my-branch" was branched out from "version/1" branch. Now, a "version/2" branch is created, that is branched out from "version/1" that had some commits after me branching out the feature branch.

I want to merge "feature/my-branch" to "version/2" branch. To do it I use:

```
git rebase version/2
```

There are no conflicts between my branch and "version/2" branch. But still I have to go through all commits:

- Accept all current changes in all files changed by particular commit
- Save all files
- I have to execute:

  ```
  git add -A
  ```
- And then continue to next commit:

  ```
  git rebase --continue
  ```

There are no conflicts, but git rebase wants to go through all commits every time. So I have to accept each and every change in every commit that was made in-between. It seems it should not work that way.

How to fix it?

Comment: If you want to rebase `my-branch` to `version/2`, shouldnt you be doing `git rebase my-branch` when on `version/2` ?

Comment: Please don't [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70376184/3001761). As we've already been though, what you're describing is not the behaviour of rebase. From what you've posted we can't see git's config or status, what the changes it's asking you to add are, ... Even in this case you can create a [mre] in a clean repo.

Comment: @leoOrion no, that would cause version/2's new commits to be rewritten on top of my-branch's commits. In the one-argument form `git rebase <branch>` you want to be checked out on the branch that should _change_ (but the direction doesn't really matter for this question).

Comment: I think i am  missing some context here.  `I want to merge "feature/my-branch" to "version/2" branch` . This implies my first comment.

Comment: @leoOrion ah I see what you mean - my interpretation of that was that the OP wants to be able to cleanly merge (or squash or fast forward) my-branch into version/2, so wants to rebase the former onto the latter. Again I'm not sure the direction really matters for what they're asking though.

Comment: Without the exact topology you are starting with and the transcript of what you said to Git and what Git said to you, this is all meaningless fluff and the question is pointless. And please do not repeat a question you have already asked: that is grounds for moderator intervention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best solution is on branch two to squash all of your commits.

Then rebase off of 1.
This will simplify the merge.

I've had similar issues but that were caused by some local commit in my branch being in conflict but I know I fixed it in a later commit but trying to track through multiple commits on a branch is a nightmare.

Squash your branch and then it should remove the pain of figuring out what its btchng about.